# How to Resume Twitter Sample Stream V2 using Tweetinvi

Tags: c#, tweetinvi

I want to resume Twitter sample stream V2 after doing some calculations.
Initially I'm streaming few tweets (e.g. 100 or 1000 tweets), after receiving those I'm stopping the stream (using "sampleStreamV2.StopStream()" method provided by **Tweetinvi Sample Stream V2**) and doing some calculations. But after stopping not able to resume the stream using **Tweetinvi**.

Comment: You should post the code you have tried so far.